# ruby excercise for name.lenth.t_s

Tags: ruby, variable-length

the excercise in the book says that I should ask for the names individually and then get the name length.  I am stuck on the 8th line?  Is that what I am supposed to do to get the name?

```
    puts "What\'s your first name?"
    first = gets.chomp
    puts "What\'s your middle name?"
    middle = gets.chomp
    puts "What\'s your last name?"
    last = gets.chomp
    puts "So, your full name is #{first} #{middle} #{last}." 
    name = # {first} #{middle} #{last}
    puts "Did you know that are + #{name.length.t_s} + characters "
    puts "in your + name + "
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It should be (using ruby string embedding):

```
name = "#{first} #{middle} #{last}"
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html

Comment: Yes, but I am still getting this as my outcome: Did you know that there are + name.length.t_s + characters
in your + name + ?

Comment: Ahh, got it. Here you go: `puts "Did you know that are + #{name.length.to_s} + characters in your #{name}"` You’ve had two typos in the output.

Comment: It doesn't work. It says: `<main>': undefined method `t_s' for 18:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Comment: You again missed `o`. The method is called `to_s` which is for “TO STRING”.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I really appreciate it so much!  And sorry for my careless oversight!